# Xampp not accessing htdocs folder on localhost

Tags: xampp, htdocs

My localhost is not pointing to ht docs when I type in browser localhost it directly points to a sub-directory which is in ht docs like this ht docs>> blog>>'index. Php it is directly pointing to index.php which is inside blog folder and blog folder is inside ht docs. What should I do?
This  blog  folder  is a Laravel project.